# ASP.NET Menu control not respecting padding values in IE or FF

Tags: asp.net, css

I have set ridiculous padding values and cannot get padding to extend the total width beyond the content size.  Isn't FF supposed to follow a "box model" whereby padding is added to the content size?  Here's the relevant code.

Environment:
IE7, FF 3.6.8

CSS:

```
.StaticMenuStyle
{
    width: auto;
    background-image: url(../images/nav_repeat.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    padding-left: 100px;
    /*padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;*/
    float:left;
}  
.StaticMenuStyle a:link
{
    padding-left: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
}  
.StaticMenuItemStyle
{
    height: 38px;
    /*min-width: 75px;*/
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align: center;    
    color:#006c56;
    padding-left: 100px;
    /*padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border:5px solid clear;
    /*margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;*/
    /*background: right 50% url(../images/nav_div.gif) no-repeat;*/
    background-image: url(../images/nav_div.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    /*text-indent:5px;*/
}
/*
.StaticSelectedStyle
{
    color:#006c56;
    height: 38px;
    background-image: url(../images/nav_over.gif);
    background-position:center bottom;
    overflow:hidden;
}
*/
.StaticHoverStyle
{
    /*color:Black;*/
    /*color:White;*/
    /*height: 38px;*/
    /*background-image: url(../images/nav_over.gif);*/
    /*background-position:center bottom;*/
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
}
.StaticMenuStyle a:hover
{
    /*background-image: none;*/
    height: 38px;
    background-image: url(../images/nav_over.gif);
    background-position:center bottom;
    color:Black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.DynamicMenuStyle
{
    height: 38px;
    /*width: auto;*/
}
```

ASP.NET

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SJMTemplateDot4.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<%--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">--%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource2" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false"  />
     <asp:Menu 
                ID="MenuMain" 
                runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource2"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                StaticMenuStyle-cssClass="StaticMenuStyle"
                StaticMenuItemStyle-cssClass="StaticMenuItemStyle"
                StaticHoverStyle-cssClass="StaticHoverStyle"
                />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the padding being overiden in another CSS file, perhaps?  Try `padding-left: 100px !important`.

Also, as I mentioned in my comment, you should install [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com).  It can both tell you the actual computed padding value of each element AND it can show you excellent visual models of the exact dimensions of an element, including padding and margin.

[IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) can help with IE.

Comment: I created no other CSS files, you have all the code in the simplified example. I never used FireBug, but from what I can gather the padding-left values are all "crossed-out"/disabled. There is an ID selector in my Style called #MenuMain (the ID of the asp.net menu item). This ID selector was NOT created by me, so it must be generated by the control itself.

Comment: !important did the trick!  Nice, I haven't seen that one before.